# libqmi - Transaction timed out

Tags: networking, usb, mobile, 3g

I'm trying to test quectel ec21 3G module on my raspberry pi board. I have the kernel configured as per supplied datasheet and the module itself is detectable by the system because I can see cdc-wdm0 and ttyUSB{0,1,2,3} in /dev directory. Furthermore when testing AT commands on ttyUSB2 I'm getting appropriate responses.

But, when trying to run command such as:

```
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -p --nas-get-signal-strength
```

I'm getting:

```
error: couldn't create client for the 'nas' service: CID allocation failed in the CTL client: Transaction timed out
```

What is this indicative of ? what is the real issue here and how can I solve it ?